# Is there any limitations in using date pickers for Google sheets in mobiles/Iphones?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a sheet that works fine on computers,  but I want to be able to use it on my mobile device as well, but I can't seem to access the date picker. Do I have to enable anything for that or is it just not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes off course I can! I just didn’t think I had to, thought it was a simple yes or no question :) I’ll pass a copy later today. Thanks!

Comment: here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OHdTH_Z5lm-FWcJ0SYAF9eaetZ07PyOJDfEf-1mPqio/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so, on a Mac/computer I get a date Picker ny double-click on the upper row for a month. But on a iPhone it is just a simple cell/textField. I Cant get that date-picker to show. Thanks for any advice/help!

Comment: Which cell has the date picker in?

Comment: Hi, i am not sure how the sheet looks for you but there should be a date picker in C5 to Z5 and every second row from that to December month. But I can not see that on my iPhone, only on my Mac. Can you see it?

Comment: I can not see it on desktop. I created a copy so that I could have edit access, but still no date pickers are there.

Comment: That’s weird. Not in this either? I worked in it yesterday and there was a date picker. I got it by rightklick and choose “data validation” and choose “date”. So, by doubbleklick, you don’t get any date picker?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OHdTH_Z5lm-FWcJ0SYAF9eaetZ07PyOJDfEf-1mPqio/edit

Comment: Seems like you’re right, picker works on desktop but not on mobile nor the app. I don’t think there’s a way to do this on mobile; maybe send feedback from within the mobile app and add the details as a suggestion?

Comment: Thanks, yea, I probably should. Thanks for taking your time!